# Difference between GINGERBREAD.DDLJ1 and GINGERBREAD.DDMA3 build number on Samsung Galaxy Y Duos?

Tags: 2.3-gingerbread, device-firmware, samsung-galaxy-y-duos

I am using Samsung Galaxy Y Duos phone. Today, my phone showed the notification for software update. So, I clicked on it and installed the updates. The update was more than 12 MB in size.

Before update, my phone was showing GINGERBREAD.DDLJ1 build number. Now, it is GINGERBREAD.DDMA3.

I Googled for it, but did not get any information about it. Is this build number given by Samsung or Google? How will I know what this update changed, or what new features it added to my phone? How will I know what performance impacts it has on my phone?

Normally whenever we update the app, it shows changelog about changes or new features to be added to that app. But, they are not providing any kind of changelog after the OS update.

Comment: Give it a little bit more time... If that version is new, it's possible there are no changelogs (update info) for the OS yet.

Comment: Did the Android subversion change? Ex. 2.3.4 to 2.3.5

Comment: @ZnewmaN: no it is still 2.3.6

Answer (score 1, accepted):

DDLJ1 and Builds starting from DD are the roms basically made for Indian based samsung models. These are official update pushed by Samsung called OTA updates. For more info on samsung's builds you ca refer http://www.sammobile.com/firmwares/1/

Answer (score 0):

Check your internal memory. It will not be increased but the apps will take less load on internal memory. And there will be better stability.

Comment: Please don't use ALL CAPS

Comment: I didn't feel any difference in performance of my phone.